# Take input from one csv and write to a second csv

Tags: python, csv

i am pulling data from one csv and get 2 different variables that are location in different formats one is for a single floor and the other is for multiple floors.  my code to pull the data works as expected, i am having troubles writing to the correct rows in the second csv, the data is writing but it is doing this letter by letter.

```
import csv
infile = open('vlan_dev.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(infile)
outfile = open('testout.csv', 'w')
writer  = csv.writer(outfile)
used_header = False
for row in reader:
    # skip over the CSV header
    if not used_header:
        used_header = True
        continue

    #defining variables
    building = row[3]
    startfloor = row[4]
    endfloor = row[5]
    subnet = row[6]
    mask = row[10]
    location1 = building.replace(' ', '')+startfloor
    location2 = building.replace(' ', '')+startfloor+'-'+endfloor
    iprange = subnet+'/'+mask
    if (building != 'NETWORK CORE' and subnet.startswith('10.96.')):
        if startfloor == endfloor:
            print location1
            writer.writerow(location1)
        elif startfloor != endfloor:
            print location2
            writer.writerow(location2)
        location = location1 + location2
        print location
```

I have tried a few options for the second part and am having troubles writing correctly. The above takes the correct output but writes it a single letter per cell. I have tried other options but am at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writerow` expects an iterable, and strings are iterated character-by-character. Try :

```
 writer.writerow([location2])
```

Comment: if i wanted to write to row[2] instead of the first row, how would i edit the command to change where to write.

Comment: @Waitkus you would have to include two blank columns, e.g. `["", "", location2]`